# How to keep assigned attributes to a queryset object after filtering? Alternatives?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-queryset

Maybe it's a stange answer, so i will explain why i'm doing this.

I have a model of **Products**. I have to assign each of them some **stock**.

So i have **a function** on the Products model that calculates a lot of neccesary things like stock and **returns a QuerySe**t.

Since my db model is a little bit "complicated" i can't use annotations in this case. So i decided to execute this database query manually and then, **assign each product on the querySet a stock attribute manually**. Something like:

```
for product in queryset_products:
    product.stock = some_stock_calc...
```

The problem comes when i want to use **filters** this queryset_product.
after executing something like:

```
queryset_products = queryset_products.filter(...)
```

the stock attribute gets **lost**

**Any solution?**

Comment: AFAIK, the only solution will be [Django QS **`annotate`** function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#annotate)

Comment: I don't think you can do it this way. Because [querysets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy). Objects are only created when accessed. Maybe `@property` can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't use `annotate()`, if you can add a separate column to store `stock` in your `Product` table, you can make a the `filter` queries any time.
Maybe have a `celery` task that does all the calculations for each `Product` and save to new column.

Otherwise, without `annotate` you can't have the `stock` attribute in the queryset.

Answer (score 0):

All operations on the queryset like `.filter()` are symbolic until the queryset is enumerated. Then an SQL query is compiled and executed. It is not effective to calculate the stock on a big unfiltered queryset and then even to run it again filtered. You can split the filter to conditions unrelated to stock appended to the queryset and then a filter related to stock that you evaluate in the same Python loop where you calculate the stock.

```py
result = []   
for product in queryset_products.filter(**simple filters):
    product.stock = some_stock_calc...
    if product.stock > 0 or not required_on_stock:
        result append(product)
```

A cache field of possible active products that could be on stock is very useful for the first simple filter.

Maybe the stock calculation is not more complicated then e.g. a stock at midnight plus a sum of stock operations since midnight. Then the current stock can be calculated by a [`Subquery`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) in an annotation and filtered together. It will by compiled to one SQL with a main query with joins to your related models and a relative simple subquery for stock. (That would be another question.)

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved differently, you can run one loop as

```
queryset_products = list(queryset_products.filter(...))

for product in queryset_products:
   setattr(product, "stock") = some_stock_calc...
```

Basically, you need to fetch all the records from the database as query being lazy it will be lost since it will be re-evaluated unless results have been cached/stored.